# How to call DocuSign Envelope using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I'm trying to call a DocuSign REST end point to get an Envelope, please refer to this url.

[DocuSign Get Envelope](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/)

I'm using a .NET/C# console application.
**My problem is to create the authentication token and use it with the url provided in the page to retrieve an envelope/document**.

I have all needed requirements inside DocuSign in place that is an account, clientid, private-key, a development environment and lots of already created envelopes/documents.

All I need is a complete code example that creates the token and calls the endpoint that retrieves the envelopeid.

I have already tried extracing an envelope using the github repository at:
[text](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp)

However this is not the way I want to go. I need to call the REST endpoint without the wrapper-classes, hence the C#/.NET code provided in the repository is not helpfull.

EDIT

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var accessToken = JWTAuth.AuthenticateWithJWT(
            "ESignature",
            "clientId",
            "ImpersonatedUserId",
            "account-d.docusign.com", //AuthServer
            DSHelper.ReadFileContent("private.key")
        );

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/" + clientId + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/documents/1/";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
            Content = new StringContent("some json", Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)
        };

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

As mentioned earlier, Im trying to use the approach in this page:

[DocuSign API Get Envelope](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've provide some code, put as mentioned I'm not sure about how to integrate the token with the get request.

Answer (score 0):

First, just an obvious mistake in your code where you have:

```
 string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/" + clientId + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/documents/1/";
```

Should instead be:

```
 string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/" + accountId + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/documents/1/";
```

Second, I highly recommend you download a quickstart C# code to see how it's done.
Also, you should use the v2.1 API, not the v2.0
Since you're using the C# SDK, you should use it to make the API call, not direct/raw call.
Your C# code can look like this:

```
        var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(basePath);
        docuSignClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(docuSignClient);

        // Step 1. Make the envelope request body
        EnvelopeDefinition envelope = MakeEnvelope(signerEmail, signerName, ccEmail, ccName, envStatus, gatawayAccountId, gatewayName, gatewayDisplayName);

        // Step 2. call Envelopes::create API method
        // Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
        return results.EnvelopeId;
```

To download an envelope and its documents use this code:

```
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);

// EnvelopeDocuments::get.
// Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
System.IO.Stream results = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId,
                envelopeId, docSelect);

// Look up the document from the list of documents 
EnvelopeDocItem docItem = documents.FirstOrDefault(d => docSelect.Equals(d.DocumentId));
```

Comment: I can't see where you are retrieving an existing envelope using the id

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/